# Who was the first comic book superhero without a secret identity?

Tags: comics, history-of

Even if it's absolutely easy to find out. Who was the first comic book superhero without a secret identity?

Super heroes only, comics only.

Comment: Marvel's first "super-hero", Namor, never had a secret identity that I know of, but I suspect there were earlier ones...

Comment: Pansy Yokum? Popeye?

Comment: Comic **books** only? If the superhero appeared in a newspaper comic **strip** some time before appearing in a comic **book**, which date do we go by?

Comment: The Fantastic Four all went by their real names, even Ben Grimm, who looked nothing like his old self after becoming the Thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd say Buck Rogers, in 1929. He is considered a super hero, had no secret identity, and he altough he appeared first in a book its comics came out soon after, as said in 1929.

If, anyway, you prefer something more "super" than "hero", then I'd say Doctor Occult, 1935, whom -if I remember correctly- just choose Doctor Occult as a "working name", not as a secret identity.

Comment: if Buck Rogers is considered to be a hero then it works. Thanks.